# Which properties does `github.event` in a GitHub Workflow have?

Tags: continuous-integration, webhooks, github-actions

When using GitHub Actions, it is possible to access [contexts](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/contexts-and-expression-syntax-for-github-actions#contexts) in an expression. One of the contexts is the `github` context. It has a property `github.event`, which is an object.

What properties does the `github.event` object have? How can I distinguish between e.g. a push event and a tag creation event?

Comment: The same as the webhook?

Answer (score 18):

To distinguish the different events, you can always check for `github.event_name`:

```
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    if: github.event_name == 'push'
```

The properties of `github.event` depend on what kind of event was triggered. They are documented in the "Event Types & Payload" section of the [REST API v3 documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/). The section "Webhook events" of the "[Events that trigger workflows](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#webhook-events)" documentation contains links to every object in the "Webhook event payload" column.

## Example

You have a [create](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#create-event-create) event, therefore `github.event_name == 'create'`. You can access the following properties in your `workflow.yml` (as described in [Event Types & Payload / CreateEvent](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#createevent))

- `${{ github.event.ref_type }}`
- `${{ github.event.ref }}`
- `${{ github.event.master_branch }}`
- `${{ github.event.description }}`

### Complete workflow example

This is a single workflow, which runs different jobs depending on whether it was triggered by a push or a tag creation event.

- Runs tests on pushes and tag creations
- Packages the application on any tag
- Deploys the app when the tag starting with `v`

```
name: CI

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  create:
    tags:

jobs:

  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04

    steps:
      - <YOUR TESTSTEPS HERE>

  dist:
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    if: github.event_name == 'create'

    steps:
      - <YOUR BUILDSTEPS HERE>
      - name: Upload artifact
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: mypackage
          path: dist

  deploy:
    needs: dist
    runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
    if: github.event_name == 'create' && startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/v')
    # This does the same:
    # if: github.event_name == 'create' && github.event.ref_type == 'tag' && startsWith(github.event.ref, 'v')

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v1
        with:
          name: mypackage
      - <YOUR DEPLOY STEPS HERE>
```

Note that `github.ref` and `github.event.ref` differs:

- `github.ref == 'refs/tags/v1.2.5'`
- `github.event.ref == 'v1.2.5'`

Comment: I don't know if this worked before. But it doesn't now. `on.create.tags[]` doesn't capture new tag events. For instance it runs on a pull request. You should change it to `on.push.tags[]`. Also you should change the `github.event_name` to push.  Then this will work.